# emulator: ERROR: GLES emulation: Could not find required symbol (createOpenGLSubwindow)

Tags: android, android-emulator

[Click to view my Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlmMU.png)   My emulator was working fine since I bought my PC (around a month). Suddenly I am facing this error. The error in my console is as follows

```
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23
emulator: ERROR: GLES emulation: Could not find required symbol (createOpenGLSubwindow): Could not find symbol
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation library mismatch. Be sure to use the correct version!
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation library could not be initialized!
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete the emulator and create the new emulator by changing the system image as for your cpu processor.